# UI-Grid row aggregate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

As I'm using angular ui-grid, I'm looking for a way to get sum of rows.

Basically I have a timesheet model grid where users will clock their work logs. The last column will show the total number of hours worked per week. This will be the sum of row items. How do we do this?

All examples lead to column aggregates but now row.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always add a column at last, specify a template for the cell, and inside the template you will have access to row.entity, write a function that takes the row as input, traverses it for all 'keys' and sums them up, returns the summation. Call the function from the template, so in each angular 'tick' you will get updated values.